# 6 months old cat won't stop suckling his grandmother

Tags: cats, feeding

I have this six months old cat who's adorable but crazy lol

He's the offspring (Chubbs) of the daughter (Luna) of my female cat (Mara), which I gave to my step daughter but now Chubs won't stop suckling on Mara and she doesn't stop him from doing it. Obviously she doesn't produce milk.

How do I stop it?
To clarify 
Mara is the mother of Luna
Luna is the mother of Chubs
Chubs suckles on Mara.